# How can I implement a shared calendar with another Windows Phone

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, calendars, family-room

My girlfriend just recently got a Windows Phone, and she can't stand it. It's too "high tech" for her. However, I think she will find one thing beneficial, if I can figure out how to do it.

Obviously, Microsoft recently discontinued 'Rooms' ('Family Room'). So, here's my conundrum. Let's say that my girlfriend and I decide that we're going to go and visit my parents next weekend. By the time that comes around, she will have forgotten, and it's not uncommon for her to make other plans by accident. However, if she could check her calendar, before making plans, that would be great!

If I add an event to a calendar, I want my girlfriend to be able to see them. I don't want to share ALL of my events with her, from ALL of my calendars, because many of my calendars are work-related, and that would frustrate her. However, if we can create a shared calendar, where we can add all of our events and see them from one place, that would be great. Is there any way to do this?

Also, I would like to try to actually get this implemented in the Calendar app, so that we can ask Cortana what we have going on on a specific day, and she will be able to display that information. Therefore, I have discovered that using GroupMe will not be very beneficial.

Also, I don't know if it's a big deal, because I'm sure we can make it work, but she has the original Windows 8.1, and I have the Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Thank you in advance to anyone who provides some constructive and helpful feedback.

Comment: If you want it on a per-event bass, you could just invite her as an attendee (which is how I do it)

Comment: And how does she receive the notification? Does she have to manually add it to her own calendar, does she get an email, etc?

Comment: She'll get an email, and it'll appear in her calendar tentatively automatically (assuming you invite her Hotmail account, or an Exchange account)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a shared calendar thusly:

1. Go to https://calendar.live.com (and log in with your Microsoft account if necessary).
2. At the top, click the arrow next to "New", and select "Calendar".
3. Enter a name and any other details, then click on "Edit sharing", and click "Save" in the pop-up that appears.
4. In the new pop-up, enter your girlfriend's name or email address, choose the permission level and click "Share".
5. Your girlfriend will get an email with the invitation and will need to click the accept link therein. She may also have to log in with her MS account, and then will be able to choose the calendar's colour, configure notifications and more.
6. After that, she can open the Calendar app on her phone, go to settings and enable the shared calendar (if it isn't enabled by default).

   If the calendar doesn't show up, have her do the following:

   - go to phone settings → email+accounts
   - long-press on "Microsoft account" and tap "sync"
   - this will refresh all Outlook.com data, including calendars

Now, any events you create in the shared calendar will automatically show up on her phone, and vice versa (if you gave her the permissions to create new events).

Comment: Fantastic advice! This is kinda the route I was headed before, but I didn't realize that syncing the calendar for the main Live account worked differently than any other account. I will definitely show her how to set this up. So, once I create the initial calendar on the computer, I don't have to use a computer to do anything else, correct? I can add events with my phone, and they will then show up on her phone? And, will Cortana pick them up if I add an event for a day and she asks what's going on for that day?

Comment: @Ryan Correct, only the initial set-up needs to be done via the live.com website. Everything else (adding/editing events and so on) can be done on your phone. And yes, Cortana will pick up events from a shared calendar.

Comment: @Ryan and you you already had a Family Room calendar it will continue to working as a relugar shared calendar.

Comment: Indreks suggestion sounds great, but the shared calendar never shows up in the calendar on my Lumia 950XL. Or on my wife's Android phone, for that matter. We have used our old Rooms calendar to great satisfaction until she switched to Android, and now she has only reading rights... Sigh! Why must MS constantly remove functionality and replace it with a mess?

Answer (score -1):

This video will show you how to share your calendar event with other: [How to shared calendar with another Windows Phone](http://youtu.be/QHNJdl0B4ek)

Comment: Please summarise the steps involved in your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged because they can become useless if the link ever goes down. For more information, see [How do I write a good answer?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)